# Connect FortiClient IPsec VPN via Ubuntu 18.04 KDE

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, ipsec

I have just installed FortiClient 6.0.0.0029 in Ubuntu 18.04 - KDE.

I'm not shure, but looks like Linux's FortiClient has only SSL connection but not **IPsec** (which I need)...

Works ok in Windows 10, but mine has some bugs and I prefer to work with Ubuntu whenever possible. There is a form with:

- Connection type (SSL-VPN / IPsec VPN)
- Connection Name
- Description
- Remote Gateway
- Authentication Method (PreShared key in my case)
- Authentication (XAuth)
- Username

My company sent me only the data to fill that form, but I can't find anything like that in Ubuntu's version of FortiClient6.

Does anyone know an alternative to connect with linux, using that data? Maybe I don't need to use FortiClient specifically.

Thanks in advance!﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [Strongswan](https://www.strongswan.org/) which is the recommended IPSec initiator-responder in Ubuntu. You can install it from Ubuntu's repository i.e.: `sudo apt-get install strongswan`.

There are many ways to configure it: editing the legacy `ipsec.conf` file or using the `swanctl` tool. To install swanctl simply use `sudo apt-get install strongswan-swanctl`. If you're using Ubuntu Desktop then you can use the GUI to configure Strongswan just install the Strongswan module for Network Manager (`sudo apt-get install network-manager-strongswan`).

**Command line config**

A swanctl example config should look something like this:

- Create a new cofig file into `/etc/swanctl/config.d/` (`work.conf` or whatever)
- Open that file with your favourite editor and setup the proper config which is going to be something like this:

  ```
  connections {

      ikev1-psk-xauth {

          dpd_delay = 30
          dpd_timeout = 90
          version = 1
          remote_addrs = vpn.yourcompany.com

          local-1 {
              auth = psk
          }

          local-2 {
              auth = xauth
              xauth_id = username
          }

          remote-1 {
              auth = psk
          }

          children {
              ikev1-psk-xauth {
                  remote_ts = 0.0.0.0/0
                  dpd_action = restart
                  close_action = start
                  start_action = start
              }
          }
      }
  }

  secrets {
      ike-psk-remote {
          id = vpn.yourcompany.com
          secret = "this-is-the-shared-password" 

      }
      ike-psk-local {
          id = username
          secret = "this-is-the-user-xauth-password" 
      }

  }
  ```

Save the config file then issue `swanctl --load-all` to start the connection. To check the status issue `swanctl --list-sas` and check out that the SAs are up and running.

This config is not tested and probably wont work as it is.

**GUI config**

Here is a guide with screenshots too: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/NetworkManager

Comment: Now that's what I call **explanation**! Thanks, I will try it as soon as possible!

Answer (score -1):

forticlient  6 for linux does NOT do vpn.

check this out instead :

https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!

Comment: I downvoted your answer because openfortivpn does not do IPSEC, just SSL.